# When the user logs in how can I get that particular users details?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a project where there are multiple users and each user can have any number of courses. When a user logs in I want to display only the courses for that particular user. The tables and its records are-

**User**

- UserId
- UserName
- Password

**Course**

- CourseId
- CourseName

**UserCourse**

- Id
- UserId
- CourseId

In home controller I am writing the code as -

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (Entities dc = new Entities())
        {
            var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                Session["LoggedUserID"] = v.UserId.ToString();
                Session["LoggedUserName"] = v.UserName.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Course");
            }
        }
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

Then I created a new controller with template MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework named UserController.

In UserController I have written code for getting particular users course details as-

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int userId = (int)Session["LoggedUserID"];

        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.UserId==userId);
        if (user != null)
            return View(user); // this

        return View();
    }
}
```

I am getting all the users courses after logging in when I  want only that users details. What should I do? Please do help.

Comment: Where are you selecting the courses? Please put that code in the question.

Comment: The courses are already specified in the Course table and in UserCourse table I am giving reference to the userId as well as CourseId which shows which user has selected which course

Comment: Ok, but you have shown only the table structure here. Can you show your `User` model? So that I can understand the navigational properties. Or put the view code that is using the User model.

Comment: Stop! You're saving user passwords in plain tex!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out. I had to pass the userId as well as the course for that user into the view. My latest working code is shown below. Hope it helps others.

**HomeController:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (DetailsEntities dc = new DetailsEntities())
        {
            var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                Session["User"] = v;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course");
            }
        }
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

**CourseController:**

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User user = (User)Session["User"];
        var usr = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            var course = db.UserCourses.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId);
            if (usr != null)
                return View(course);
        }
        return View(usr);
    }
}
```